# If I use an SSH tunnel to forward a remote port to a local one, and my IP address changes, will that tunnel still work?

Tags: ssh, ip, ssh-tunneling

Simple - trying to use my personal computer as a server, by forwarding a public static IP address's port to mine, but I'm worried about Comcast pulling out the rug from underneath my feet and changing my IP address. If that happens will the SSH tunnel persist or no? Should I just use DDNS?

Comment: The short answer is your concerns are correct.  Better approach is to use cron to automate the connection.  Have it check the status of the SSH connection and start it if needed.  Article should get you up and running http://www.brandonchecketts.com/archives/creating-a-permanent-ssh-tunnel-between-linux-servers

Answer (score 3):

Quoting [Comcast Business Internet](http://business.comcast.com/internet/business-internet/static-ip):

> Static IP is not supported on retail devices due to technical
>   limitations. Static IP is only supported via Comcast Business CCR &
>   BWG leased devices: CCR (Comcast Commercial Routers: SMC D3G-CCR or
>   Netgear CG3000DCR) / BWG (Business Wireless Gateways: Cisco DPC3939B
>   or Cisco DPC3941B). For more information on CCR and BWG devices,
>   please see more at: [DOCSIS Device
>   Information Center](http://mydeviceinfo.comcast.net/)

---

Doing what you ask expressly violates your Residential Consumer AUP.  Not hampering with the normal flow of DHCP would not violate your Residential Consumer AUP, therefore DynDNS is your best option.  Another includes buying a Cheap Domain and enabling Virtual Hosting

Comment: I'm aware of the fact that static IP is not an option with residential Comcast, which is why I'm proposing I ssh-tunnel into a static IP VPS, but I have a feeling that the ssh-tunnel would not persist through new DHCP leases in case Comcast updates my IP. Virtual hosting is not an option - I'm trying to use a personal computer as a server.

Comment: Then using DynDNS is your only Option, see [Having problems with ssh and dyndns](http://www.dyncommunity.com/questions/9658/having-problems-with-ssh-and-dyndns.html)