# Postfix on Centos7 not accepting Public port 25

Tags: centos, postfix

I have a new mailserver (`postfix`) on a new CentOS7 install. I can connect (`telnet`) on `127.0.0.1` port 25 and on the public IP from the local machine but not on the public IP outside the machine. I use IPTables and have triple verified it is correct. In fact I also have Apache HTTP on the machine with a port 80 rule in `iptables` and it works just fine. `firewalld` is not running. Nothing is in my hosts.allow or hosts.deny.

```
telnet 127.0.0.1 25 or telnet x.x.x.x: (from same machine)
Connected to 127.0.0.1.
Escape character is '^]'.
220 ga003.example.com ESMTP Postfix

telnet x.x.x.x (from outside):
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection timed out

telnet x.x.x.x 80 (from outside):
Trying 74.206.115.232...
Connected to 74.206.115.232.
Escape character is '^]'.
```

Netstat:

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:25      0.0.0.0:*          LISTEN      26502/master
```

ps ax:

```
26502 ?        Ss     0:00 /usr/libexec/postfix/master -w
```

iptables:

```
-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 25 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
```

/etc/postfix/main.cf:

```
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = all
```

From MX Toolbox:

```
Connection attempt #1 - Unable to connect after 15 seconds
```

I see nothing in `/var/log/messages` or `/var/log/maillog`

Comment: It might be useful to know your full iptables rules.

Comment: Some home ISPs block outgoing connections on port 25.

Comment: In Regards to the answer below, see: [If I use an SSH tunnel to forward a remote port to a local one, and my IP address changes, will that tunnel still work?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/220007/if-i-use-an-ssh-tunnel-to-forward-a-remote-port-to-a-local-one-and-my-ip-addres).  Same issue, but possibly different ISP's, as @user1794469 states.

Comment: @DaveGardner: Your `telnet x.x.x.x 80` exhibit is somewhat unconvincing.  How do know for sure that you’re using the right IP address?  Maybe you’re connecting to some other machine that’s listening on port 80 (but not port 25).  If you can access a web page that you know is being served on this machine and nowhere else, that would be a good thing to mention.  Also, as I said in my other comment(s), if you have other machines on the same local LAN, serviced by the same ISP connection, then test results regarding those other machines belong in the question.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely your ISP is blocking 25, unless you pay for business service.

Comment: No. I am at a Co-Location center and I have other servers running using these ports on other IP's I have in my range. No ports are blocked there. Also I cannot get in on port 25 from other servers at the CoLo on the same IP subnet connected by a switch.

Comment: @DaveGardner: (1) This sounds like information that should be [edit](http://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/227740/edit)ed into the question, and not hidden in a comment on an answer — especially an answer that, arguably, *should* have been a comment, and therefore may be at risk of deletion.  (2) I say “… sounds like …” because I’m not sure what you’re saying.  The term “Co-Location center” is unfamiliar to me.  … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  I guess you are saying something like “I have multiple machines on a subnet, behind the same firewall, serviced by the same ISP connection, and we have ‘business service’.  I can connect to the other machines on port 25 from the outside Internet.  But even the other local machines cannot connect to this new machine on port 25.”  You might want to put something like that (corrected, if necessary) into your question, with a description of the data path between the other machines and your new machine (e.g., same IP subnet connected by a switch).

Answer (score 0):

Found it. I did an "iptables -L" to list and check the active firewall rules and found the port 25 rule was defined as UDP. Must have been from something previous. I refreshed iptables again and it picked up TCP port 25 rule as defined. All is working perfectly now.